# Exercise 2.3 from Eloquent Javascript - about execution performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am revisiting exercise 2.3 from  Eloquent Javascript, by Marijn Haverbeke.

I got one working solution, which follows below:

```
var size = 8;
for(var y = 0;y < size; y++) {
  var c = "";
  for(var x = 0;x < size; x++) {
    if((y+x) % 2 == 0)
      c += " ";   
    else
      c += "#";
  }
  console.log( c + "\n");
}
```

The Author's solution is as follows:

```
var size = 8;

var board = "";

for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
      board += " ";
    else
      board += "#";
  }
  board += "\n";
}


console.log(board);
```

My question: What can be said about both scripts from a performance point of view (i.e. utilizes the least resources) and why?

Thanks in advance,
J

Comment: why don't you run a perf test yourself?

Comment: What is `console.log`? Depends a lot on what it is doing for how any ressources are used.

Comment: Hello @charlietfl, I ran the perf test online, at http://goo.gl/1edO9b
yet part of my question is why it runs faster. I want to understand the concept behind the scenes.

Comment: biggest difference would likely be a call to console function on every iteration vs once for other

Comment: That's what I hinted charlie, thanks! I was kind of expecting an answer a bit more scholarly.